# Spacing between divs in text?

Tags: css, spacing

Here is a little css problem

The code:

```
     printf( '<div id="replyto">Reply to</div>
    <a class="replytolink" href="%1$s">%2$s %3$s</a>',
 $parent_link, $parent->comment_author, $parent->comment_date );
```

The css:

```
#replyto {
        float: left;
}
.replytolink {
        float: left;
}
```

is output

Reply to["Comment author Date"](http://www.example)

How can I output it

Reply to ["Comment author Date"](http://www.example)

with correct spacing between text and link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a semantic point of view, using a floating div followed by an anchor isn't the best choice possible of tags in this case.
Personally, I would replace that `div` with a `span`, then you wouldn't need to float them, and so word spacing would work as usual..

Answer (score 0):

Add a space?

```
printf( '<div id="replyto">Reply to </div><a class="replytolink" href="%1$s">%2$s %3$s</a>', $parent_link, $parent->comment_author, $parent->comment_date );
```

Or add `padding-right: 2em` on `#replyto`.

Comment: I tried adding blank spaces but it makes no difference. Is 5px consistent with empty space between words regardless of font, font size etc?

Comment: you could use padding-right:2em; or similar for relative spacing, just a thought really.

Comment: 5px is perfectly acceptable with normal font-size, but if the font-size is large the space needs to be adjusted. I guess it's not worth to break my back over this though.

Comment: @sarytash, following Danjah's advice, I've updated my post. 2em (adjust as necessary) should work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `padding-right` to `#replyto`:

```
#replyto {
        float: left;
        padding-right:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.replytolink {
    padding-left:5px;
    float: left;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/RTFb7/

Comment: Thank you. See my reply above.

Answer (score 0):

Solution by *Lucius*:

```
printf( '<span>reply to <a href="%1$s">%2$s %3$s</a></span>', $parent_link, $parent->comment_author, $parent->comment_date );
```

Neat. No CSS is required. Give the `<span>` tag an ID if needed. The extra blank space after "reply to " is now output.